# Is Active record joins in Relational database a overhead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, orm, relational-database

I have a question about the ORM **ActiveRecord** and **Relational databases** (e.g. in Rails):

I'm just confused that joins (e.g. inner join) won't happen in the database layer and if I'm correct, ActiveRecord makes several queries and then join records itself...

Isn't that an overhead? Ruby is doing the database's job!
Am I wrong?
Any advise appreciated.

I was practicing Rails and wondered why no foreign key was defined in the database itself as below:

[image: MySql view with no foreign key defined]

Thank you.

Comment: I agree completely. Rails tries to reinvent a navigational database on top of a relational database. I don't use ORMs since I find SQL to be simpler and more expressive and powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Rails is lazy in loading associations.

e.g.

```
users = User.where(id: [1768, 1769, 1770])
```

will call

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1768, 1769, 1770)
```

Now for each one if you ask for user.company (for example) the database will be queried again for the appropriate company.

---

ActiveRecord also lets you do joins on the database side for a query and have it run on the database end.
e.g.

```
User.joins(:company).where(companies: {id: 5})
```

will call

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `companies` ON `companies`.`id` = `users`.`company_id` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 5
```

---

You can also load a set of records in one query, and all associations in one extra query:

```
users = User.where(id: [1768, 1769, 1770]).includes(:company)
```

will end up loading the users, then the companies

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1768, 1769, 1770)
SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies`  WHERE `companies`.`id` IN (5, 1)
```

now for each loaded user, asking `users[0].company`, for example, will used the already loaded association and will not hit the database.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer:
After some time i realized that i can define `foreign_key` for `reference` db field in **migrations** so Active record use `inner join` for queries.

```
create_table :houses do |t|  
      ...  
      t.references :house_type, foreign_key: true, index: true, null: false 
      ...    
end
```